# Change header on one page in Wordpress

Tags: php, functions

I need change the header image on just one page in Wordpress. We're using the ushuaia template, a child theme of wpcasa. It just uses a function.php page for everything. I've tried every plugin and none of them work for whatever reason. So I tried my hand at directly coding the change and added a 'forsale-image' argument to the code. It needs to go on the page 'for sale' or '8062'. Can anyone weigh in on how this should be done? Here's where the header image is created:

```
 add_filter( 'wpsight_custom_header_args', 'ushuaia_custom_header_args', 100 );

function ushuaia_custom_header_args( $args ) {

    $args['height']              = 490;
    $args['default-text-color']  = 'ffffff';
    $args['default-image']       = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/header-image.png';
    $args['forsale-image']       = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/LIV-SIR_BoR_Logo_600w.jpg';
    $args['wp-head-callback']    = 'ushuaia_header_style';

    return $args;

}

// gets included in the site header

function ushuaia_header_style() {
    $header_image = get_header_image(); 
    if( empty( $header_image ) )
        return;
    ?>
<style type="text/css">
#outer {
    background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>) no-repeat 30% -220px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the following:

```
if (is_page( 806 ) ) {
  // Your code for that page here
}
```

Comment: This isn't working? It just shows the code on the page when I do this. Any ideas? I'm editing the functions.php page directly in Smultron, saving it and replacing it on the server. No matter what I do it just shows the code I've typed and nothing else.

Comment: Where are you putting it? Don't forget it needs to be within php tags. Your posted code escapes out of PHP to HTML just before the `<style>` element.

Comment: OkI got that issue resolved but now I'm getting errors. Part of the problem is it's in the functions.php file and so I needed to add a 'get_header' call in order to use is_page. This is what I've got so far: <?php
add_action( 'get_header', function(){
$header_image = get_header_image(); 
if (is_page( 8062 ) )
  return;
 php?>
<style type="text/css">
#outer {
    background: url(<?php forsale_image(); ?>) no-repeat 30% -220px;



</style>

});